# Can't get create_window to work on a Canvas. Tkinter Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have made my own widget called 'InventorySlot' and I need the widgets within my custom one to be made onto a Canvas instead of using 'grid' or 'pack'.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')
        self.test = InventorySlot(self.root)
        self.test.grid()

class InventorySlot(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.options = {}
        self.options.update(kwargs)
        self.slot = tk.Label(self,height=3,width=6,text='',relief=SUNKEN,bg='#8b8b8b',bd=4,padx=1,pady=0)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.create_window(10,10,window=self.slot)
        self.canvas.grid()

MainTk = Main()



MainTk.root.mainloop()
```

All it shows is a blank Canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the label *after* creating the canvas. The order of creation determines the *stacking order* (ie: the z-index). The label on s there, it’s just behind the canvas.

Comment: Is there any way to re-order them?

Comment: @HastyBasher: yes. You can call `lift` to raise the label above the canvas.